# jquery post method not posting data and url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i am trying my jquery post method to post data to `index.jsp` but it does nothing.

```
    <script>
   $('input#submit').click(function(e){
  //prevent submitting the form (if there is a form)
  e.preventDefault();
    var html = $("body").html();
    var data = { 
            html: html
        };
    $.post("index.jsp", data);
});
  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="send" name="submit">`
```

Comment: are you POSTing to indx.jsp or success.jsp ?

Comment: @Sampada plz review the edits

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong URL (indx.jsp != index.jsp), change to

```
$.post("index.jsp", { data: data } );
```

if you are expecting to get the value on that page. by the way you are sending the entire html from body!